# Gradle и менеджмент конфигураций (рабочая директория для Java)

Tags: java, gradle, csv, configuration

Доброго времени суток!

Есть кроссплатформенный проект на Java в котором используются нативные библиотеки (в зависимости от платформы приложение конфигурируется по-разному).

Хочется чтобы после получения проекта из системы контроля версий проект можно было собрать и запустить нажатием одной кнопки. Для этого требуется сформировать окружение и получить откуда-то конфигурационные файлы.

1. Где хранить конфигурации и шаблоны - в CSV или репозитории Gradle?
2. Как автоматически/автоматизированно сгенерировать на основе шаблона конфигурационный файл?
3. Какие существуют лучшие практики, системы управления конфигурациями? (инструменты Grale+Artifactory+Teamcity)

Comment: Правила сайта гласят: на 1 пост 1 вопрос. Так что создайте, пожалуйста, 3 отдельных вопроса